# How to convert string to json object in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have below javascript method. I try to get the id from the data parameter.

```
data(spark, data){
    console.log('receive ', data)
    console.log(data.id)
  }
```

the first output line is `receive  {id:1}`

but the second output line is `undefined`

then I tried below method to convert the json string to object:

```
data(spark, data){
    console.log('receive ', data)
    console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)).id)
```

I still got the same output. Why can't I get the id from the input parameter?

**EDIT1**

I changed the parameter name to be different with the function name as below:

```
data(spark, d){
    console.log('receive ', d)
    console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(d)).id)
}
```

but I still got the same output.

Comment: Note that `id` should be wrapped in double quotes, then you can use `var json = JSON.parse(data); console.log(json.id);`

Comment: if the id is not wrapped in double quote, how to convert it to json object?

Comment: Why do you want to have the function name and variable name the same?

Comment: This won't work. You are using both the function name and variable name as the same string. For this kind of situation, you can do an `eval()`, but this is not at all advised.

Comment: Agreeing with Praveen, I'd recommend either changing the name of your argument, or changing the name of your function. It's very ambiguous as to what `data` could mean in your code, and it's better to err on the side of caution.

Comment: I have changed the parameter name but still got the same output

Comment: @ZhaoYi Bad approach: try `eval()` and tell?

Comment: @PraveenKumar I tried eval like this: console.log(eval(d).id)   but I got the same output

Comment: @ZhaoYi Check my answer for a working output.

Comment: Maybe you can consider to change the way you get this string?

Comment: Look at my answer it will work

Comment: Can you provide complete json string

Comment: @Sahadev the complete json string is just the first line output. It is from a websocket channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Note:** Strong word of caution. Just checking if this works, and it works. Do not use it in unexpected circumstances. **Very dangerous!**

One crazy thing is, you forgot the `function` keyword, in-front of the function name.

Trying with `eval()` for this:

```js
function data(spark, d) {
  // console.log('receive ', d);
  eval("d = " + d);
  console.log(d.id);
}
data("", "{id: 5}");
```

Comment: My function is defined inside a class (es6), so there is no function keyword. I tried your approach it works. but it is dangerous. Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: With your current implementation, I am not sure if there's a valid way.

Comment: Why doesn't JSON.parse work in this case?

Comment: @ZhaoYi It is an invalid JSON. `{id: 5}` is valid in JS, but in JSON `{"id": 5}` is valid.

Comment: @ZhaoYi Is there anything else?

Comment: @ZhaoYi Also check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41235146

Comment: The correct "solution" to this question is to have the server send down correctly formed JSON.

Comment: @torazaburo Agreed... What if the server is not under the OP's control?

Answer (score 0):

Four answers:

1. Have the server send down properly formed JSON (with double quotes around the key names). This is the preferred solution.
2. Use a relaxed JSON parser. You can search and find such things on npm.
3. Use `eval`.
4. Do some string manipulation to enclose the `id` in double quotes so you can `JSON.parse` it, or extract the `1`, or whatever you want to do. This is the least preferred solution.

Comment: **1.** What if the server is not under control? **2.** NPM? Seriously?

Comment: I'm not recommending using a relaxed/dirty parser, but I think it's better than eval. What is your problem with npm? Where else would you go looking for one?

Comment: I thought NPM is only for Node? Am I wrong?

Comment: Easy enough to use node packages in the browser with something like browserify or webpack.

Comment: And the crazy part is, you asked me not to use and you have added `eval()` as well.

Comment: Not agreeing with the Webpack thing. What if it is a shared hosting?

Comment: No, I didn't say not to use `eval`. I just said there's a better ("correct") solution.

Comment: Okay... I sincerely feel that you are missing a main major point. Let's assume the worst case. OP is using a shared hosting plus the server side is not under control. What would you recommend?

Comment: @PraveenKumar can't parse your comment about webpack. It the OP has a JS program running in a browser, then he can arrange with a bit of pre-processing to bundle a node module into his JS. This has nothing to do with where his site is hosted.

Comment: I kinda feel it would be slightly dizzy for the OP. I come from JS background and started working with WebPack and other things. It feels quite annoyed to set up stuff, but since I am using a shared hosting, none of the Node stuff I can think of. Pure HTML, CSS, JS in the client side. Just my few cents of disappointment.

Answer (score -2):

eval("(" + data + ")").id is all that is required

```js
function data(spark, data) {
  alert(eval("(" + data + ")").id);
}

data("", "{id:3}");
```

Comment: I tried but got the same output

Comment: This will work if data is `{"id":1}` but data is `{id:1}` so JSON.parse will throw an error

Comment: @slebetman try it, this will work

Comment: Can the people who downvoted this answer please explain their reasons. I can't see what is wrong with it?